# Using Method of Undetermined Coefficients to interpolating polynomial to find weights and evaluate an integral

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

I really need help on a question of using the method of undetermined coeffcients to determine some weights and then integrating it to approximate an integral. So it goes as follows:

2. We would like to approximate integrals of the form$$I(f) = \int_{-2}^{3}f(x)dx$$

for the sample points $x_{0} = −2$, $x_{1} = 0$ and $x_{2} = +2$. In other words, we seek weights
$w_{0}$,$w_{1}$,$w_{2}$ such that

$$I(f) \approx w_{0}f(-2)+w_{1}f(0)+w_{2}f(2)$$

So I am asked to find the weights via the method of undetermined coefficients for a quadrature rule with precision at least two.

I am totally stuck at this point and really need some advice.

Could someone please assist me with this ?

Thank you

Comment: For the Lagrange way, you just want to write down the Lagrange polynomial for the points $(-2,f(-2)),(0,f(0)),(2,f(2))$ and integrate it over $[-2,3]$.

Comment: Ah okay I see now. Would you know how to use the method of undetermined coefficients I seemed to have calculated that the weights are given by $\frac{5}{6}$ for $w_{0}$ and $\frac{25}{12}$ for $w_{1}$, and $\frac{25}{12}$ for $w_{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC,
to fit
$I(f) 
= \int_{-2}^{3}f(x)dx
$
by
$I(f) 
\approx w_{0}f(-2)+w_{1}f(0)+w_{2}f(2)
$,
put
$1, x, x^2$
for $f$
and find the
$w_i$
that makes it match.

When $f(x) = 1$,
$I(f) 
= \int_{-2}^{3}f(x)dx
= \int_{-2}^{3} 1\,dx
=5
$.
So this gives
$I(f)
=5 
= w_{0}+w_{1}+w_{2}
$.

When $f(x) = x$,
$I(f) 
= \int_{-2}^{3}f(x)dx
= \int_{-2}^{3} x,dx
=\frac{x^2}{2}|_{-2}^3
=\frac{3^2-(-2)^2}{2}
=\frac52
$.
This gives
$I(f)
=\frac52 
=w_{0}f(-2)+w_{1}f(0)+w_{2}f(2)
= (-2)w_{0}+(0)w_{1}+(2)w_{2}
= -2w_{0}+2w_{2}
$.

When $f(x) = x^2$,
$I(f) 
= \int_{-2}^{3}f(x)dx
= \int_{-2}^{3} x^2,dx
=\frac{x^3}{3}|_{-2}^3
=\frac{3^3-(-2)^3}{2}
=\frac{35}{2}
$.
This gives
$I(f)
=\frac{35}{2}
=w_{0}f(-2)+w_{1}f(0)+w_{2}f(2)
= (-2)^2w_{0}+(0)^2w_{1}+(2)^2w_{2}
= 4w_{0}+4w_{2}
$.

These are the
three equations in
the $w_i$.

Solve them.

By sure to check the result.

Comment: Thank you. from the method of undetermined coefficients, I found that the weights are the same as the method of using lagrange polynomials and integrating them. Would that be true ? (a gut instinct tells me yes but just wanted to confirm).

Comment: In this case, yes. However, if different base functions (instead of $1, x, x^2$) were wanted, you would get different results. For example, the functions could be $1, \cos(x), \sin(x)$. Just evaluate the integral for the three functions, get the three equations, and, presto, you are on the way to Fourier series.

Comment: If you want to derive a higher order precision with 3 points, then you would have to make the *location* of the points variable. Look up "Gaussian quadrature", for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature

Comment: Ah thank you very much, I am definitely getting a stronger overall view of numerical integration now. But sorry to bother you one last time, but this may be a bit of a trivial question where I am thinking whether it is possible for the weights to be negative, which would imply a negative area so my guess would be no right ? This is given the fact that we always integrate from the smallest point to the largest point. Again please correct me if I am wrong, thank you

Comment: The weights for Gaussian quadrature are always positive. That is proved in the link I sent you.

Comment: Sorry I meant by the method of undetermined coefficients and Lagrangian cases. Would that be the same ? Thank you

Comment: I don't think that the weights can be negative.